# Issue with table contents displaying as empty via form

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

While intending to reflect current state of tags using bootstrap 5 switches encountered into an issues. the choices are not shown properly and cannot reflect current state of switches pulled from db.
I have two tables Song and Tags. with Many-to-Many relationship. here is the code:
Models:

```
songtags = db.Table('songtags', 
                    db.Column('song_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('song.id')), 
                    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id')))

class Song(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True)
    lyrics = db.Column(db.Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    tags = db.relationship('Tags', secondary=songtags,backref="tags", lazy='dynamic')
    
    def add_tag(self, tag):
        if not self.in_tags(tag):
            self.tags.append(tag)

    def remove_tag(self, tag):
        if self.in_tags(tag):
            self.tags.remove(tag)
    
    def in_tags(self, tag):
        return self.tags.filter(
            Tags.id == tag.id).count() > 0

class Tags(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag {}>'.format(self.tag)
```

forms:

```
class TagsForm(FlaskForm):
    tags = SelectMultipleField('Tags', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add Tags')
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TagsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tags.choices = [(tag.id, tag.tag) for tag in Tags.query.all()]
```

and routes:

```
@app.route('/view_song', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_song():
    id = request.args.get('id', type=int)
    key = request.args.get('key', type=int)
    song = Song.query.get_or_404(id)
    tags = Tags.query.all()
    tagged_list = db.session.query(Tags).join(Song.tags).filter(Song.id == song.id)
    ...
    form = Transpose()
    tags_form = TagsForm()
    ...
    html = Chordpro_html(lyrics, showchords, ori_key_int, transpose)
    if song is None:
        flash('Current song does not have lyrics')
        return redirect(url_for('songbook'))
    else:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            # Handle the submit of transpose chord action
            key = form.key.data
            return redirect(url_for('.view_song', id=song.id, key=key))
        elif tags_form.validate_on_submit():
            # Handle addition of tags to a song
            selected_tags = tags_form.tags.data
            tags = Tags.query.filter(Tags.id.in_(selected_tags)).all()
            for t in tags:
                song.add_tag(t)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('.view_song', id=song.id, key=key))
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            form.key.data = song.key
            tags_form.tags.data = [tag.tag for tag in tags]
        return render_template('view_song.html', title='View Song', html=html, tagged_list=tagged_list, tags=tags, tags_form=tags_form, only_lyrics=only_lyrics, song=song, form=form, ori_key=ori_key)
```

Could some one please help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Apologies... I am new to programming and to stackoverflow. will do my best to clearly and shortly state the issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

1 solution: I was wrong to join tables and call for the list of tagged links.

fixed my code to:`tagged_list = ([tag.name for tag in song.tags])`
and everything worked after fixing my many-to-many relationship.
changes made based on [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-many-to-many-database-relationships-with-flask-sqlalchemy):

1. renamed Tags table to Tag to ease following logic,
2. fixed songtags column address for `tag_id` to `tag.id`
3. changed backref from tags to songs. this was my major mistake in
   relating two tables.
4. fixed my form to:

class TagsForm(FlaskForm):

tags = SelectMultipleField('Tags', coerce=int)

submit = SubmitField('Add Tags')

as for second issue:
in html my first error was in for loop. `{% for t in tags_form.tag %}`
when inserting `{{t.id}}` into label, ids where reflected in a form, which is addressing to id of particular tag. but my mistake was in calling for `{{ t.tag }}`, as I mistakenly thought that I was calling for a tag string. only after 3 days of digging and testing in shell I end up checking front end code. 't' is already a tag string. so by changing it to `{{ t }}` have solved my issue.

I am aware of many more issues in my code. working on appending chosen tags to songtags table and reflecting them in a form. Apologies for wasting anyone's time, who dedicated their time to solve my issues.